# FreeRADIUS EAP TLS Authenticate based on client certificate CN

Tags: tls, authentication, radius

I'd like to run FreeRADIUS for EAP TLS authentication but instead of running my own Certification Authority I'd like to use [StartSSL](https://www.startssl.com/).

I've setup EAP TLS with StartCom as the only Trusted Root CA and that works ok, but means anyone with a StartSSL Certificate could connect to my network.

I would like to allow access based on the client certificate Common Name something like `check_cert_cn = *@example.com` but I don't seem to be able to use a wild card in the `check_cert_cn` value.

Is there a way to achieve this? I might be approaching this problem the wrong way, should I be looking at realms or something? or just accept it and run my own CA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after a bit of digging I came across a [commit on GitHub](https://github.com/mcnewton/freeradius-server/commit/fbee1e9b4ce93c15d0f074ad3fdfb71ba095a4ed) that can do this.

I uncommented `virtual_server = check-eap-tls` in `eap.conf`

Then create `check-eap-tls` in `sites-available` and symlinked it to `sites-enabled`:

```
server check-eap-tls {
  authorize {
    if ("%{TLS-Client-Cert-Common-Name}" =~ /^[A-z.]*@example\.com$/) {
      update config {
        Auth-Type = Accept
      }
    }
    else {
      update config {
        Auth-Type = Reject
      }
      update reply {
        Reply-Message = "Your certificate is not valid."
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Using `=~` instead of `==` allows you to use regular expressions and in my all the certificates will be alpha with a dot so `^[A-z.]*@example\.com$` works for me.